# Microsoft Access 2010: ComboBox text extraction / search

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a text search in my form, which uses the following code to filter my table of staff data:

```
 Private Sub Command71_Click()

 DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", _

 "[Forename] Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'" & _

 "Or [Surname] Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'" & _

 "Or [ResearchArea]. Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'" & _

 "Or [Skills] Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'" & _

 "Or [EndDate] Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'"

 End Sub
```

The search works for all fields apart from [ResearchArea].
Both ResearchArea and Skills are ComboBoxes on my split form.

Both ResearchArea and Skills are fields in my Staff table.

New Skills can be added in the split form, but new ResearchArea's can only be added in the table.

The drop-down box on the Skills ComboBox contains repeated entries( e.g. if my listed skills on five staff are: "", "", "", "Accounting", "Accounting", then these options will appear in the drop-box), and blanks. I'd like it only to show unique entries, but also for me to be able to create new ones in this split form.

I'd also like to be able to search all staff's ResearchArea's, which I could do if they were text (like "Forename").

Comment: Hard time trying to figure out what exactly you're looking to do. is there something that doesn't work - if so, post the code or post the query SQL for the combobox RowSource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dot to remove on this line:

```
"Or [ResearchArea]. Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'" & _
```

Aside, you cannot search dates - in a meaningful way - as you do.

Comment: Good point about the dates. I was actually trying "[ResearchArea].text", and missed that dot. ResearchArea is not a text field, but a number - according to the design view of the Staff table.